# Exceptionhandling using Struts2 spring hibernate - best way to do it

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, struts2, error-handling

i am programming a little webApplication with Struts2, Spring and Hibernate.

So I need to catch the 400 & 500 Errors and I dont want to show the Stacktrace.

So far I have an exceptionhandling for errors like "You cant delete a user if he still has a rental" as exceptionclass in my src folder. 
Is there a way to Display them in ONE jsp or do I need to made one jsp for each exception?

I have read about the <% page isErrorPage="true" %> but is it able to show all my exceptions?
Or just the JSP exceptions like the 400 and 500 errors?

Hope you can understand my question and finding a solution would be even better :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your web.xml you can have the following configuration. So this will redirect all the general error codes which you want.

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/serverErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/login/login.action</location>
</error-page>
```

Also in your struts.xml you can have a global exception mapping which can be a single error file.

```
   <global-results>
        <!--  standard error is an ajax error page -->
        <result name="exception">/WEB-INF/pages/error-ajax.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
   <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
    </global-exception-mappings>
```

Comment: AFAIR this `<location>/login/login.action</location>` won't work.

Comment: so what do i need instead?